# RTF dynamic data columns for group of columns

Tags: xslt, rtf, dynamic-columns, word-template

I managed to display my rows into columns successfully using one column as a value following the example [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/bip/BIPRD/GUID-B9C4322A-4BBF-4D28-B8F3-435E527EE5E6.htm#BIPRD-GUID-9B87AD93-B1A1-46BD-B5D0-851215E95429)

But I am not able to find a way to show two values instead of one for each column I split, I have tried my best, but the closest thing I can get is that the template will show the first column for all the rows I am splitting consecutively, then it will show the second column value for all the columns consecutively.

**This is how my RTF looks like:**

[image: RTF sample code]

**this is how my XML looks like:**

```
<DATA_DS>
    <ASSETS_DS>
        <COMP_DESC>ABC</COMP_DESC>
        <ASTS>111</ASTS>
        <ASTS_ERC>1.2</ASTS_REC>
        <LONS>222</LONS>
        <LONS_ERC>2.2</LONS_REC>
    </ASSETS_DS>
    <ASSETS_DS>
        <COMP_DESC>EFG</COMP_DESC>
        <ASTS>333</ASTS>
        <ASTS_ERC>3.1</ASTS_REC>
        <LONS>444</LONS>
        <LONS_ERC>4.1</LONS_REC>
    </ASSETS_DS>
</DATA_DS>
```

**This is my desired output:**

[image: desired output]

**This is the current output:**

[image: current result]

But a cramped display due to my tries to merge the Description column for company name to show Value and Percentage together as shown in the first figure

So, is there a way to show Value and Percentage columns next to each other?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="DATA_DS">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
            <tr>
               <xsl:for-each select="ASSETS_DS">
                    <td> </td><td><xsl:value-of select="COMP_DESC"/></td>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="ASSETS_DS">
                    <xsl:if test="position()=1"><td> </td></xsl:if><td><xsl:value-of select="'value'"/></td><td><xsl:value-of select="'Percentage'"/></td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="ASSETS_DS">
                    <xsl:if test="position()=1"><td>Assets</td></xsl:if><td><xsl:value-of select="ASTS"/></td><td><xsl:value-of select="ASTS_REC"/></td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="ASSETS_DS">
                    <xsl:if test="position()=1"><td>Loans</td></xsl:if><td><xsl:value-of select="LONS"/></td><td><xsl:value-of select="LONS_REC"/></td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks like it will work, I am working on testing this, but will take time since i never wrote an XSLT document before